# ImportError: No module named six

Tags: python, module, importerror

I'm trying to build OpenERP project, done with dependencies. It's giving this error now

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openerp-client.py", line 105, in <module>
  File "modules\__init__.pyo", line 23, in <module>
  File "modules\gui\__init__.pyo", line 22, in <module>
  File "modules\gui\main.pyo", line 33, in <module>
  File "rpc.pyo", line 29, in <module>
  File "common\__init__.pyo", line 22, in <module>
  File "common\common.pyo", line 26, in <module>
  File "tools\__init__.pyo", line 28, in <module>
  File "dateutil\relativedelta.pyo", line 12, in <module>
ImportError: No module named six
```

Could someone guide what's wrong and how it can be fixed???

Comment: In case six is stored under the wrong Python version, see my
[kludge][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859356/error-no-module-named-six

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You probably don't have the `six` Python module installed. You can find it on [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six).

To install it:

```
$ easy_install six
```

(if you have [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/) installed, use `pip install six` instead)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a very lacking answer. Why are so many pip modules not installing their dependencies?

Comment: I have no idea why some python module incorrectly list their dependencies. Maybe the author do not test installing the module in a chroot to validate the dependencies are correct.

Comment: I needed it in my Pipfile for a web app. I used `pipenv install six`.

Comment: @StevenWade For me, I found that `pip install git+...` was the culprit; no deps were followed. Installing the pypi version, uninstalling, and then installing the git+ version pulled in the necessary dependencies, though this seems silly.

Comment: On Ubuntu for Python 2.7, I installed it with `sudo apt install python-six`. Thanks!

Answer (score 67):

If pip "says" six is installed but you're still getting:

`ImportError: No module named six.moves`

try re-installing six (worked for me):

```
pip uninstall six
pip install six
```

Comment: As you told, I could fix the issue after reinstalling six. Thank you!

Comment: For me also ... I had the package installed, but software-properties-gtk was failing. Eventually I traced it down to an import error in six. Th package python3-six was installed, but the module was not loading. I reinstalled the module with apt, and problem fixed.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: When I do this, I get `Found existing installation: six 1.16.0
Not uninstalling six at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'six'. No files were found to uninstall.`

Answer (score 34):

For Mac OS X:

```
pip install --ignore-installed six
```

Answer (score 29):

On Ubuntu and Debian

```
apt-get install python-six
```

does the trick.

Use `sudo apt-get install python-six` if you get an error saying "permission denied".

Comment: Why does debian not install the dependencies correct?

Comment: With `apt-get install python3-six` I get "newest version" but with `ipython` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'`. In `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`, `six` is not there.

Answer (score 8):

I had to `brew install six` instead, likely because I installed `awscli` through Homebrew.

Comment: I tried to add this as an edit to the accepted answer because this is also what I had to do, but there are currently too many pending edits on the Stack Overflow... so hopefully someone can do that at some point

Answer (score 5):

```
pip install --ignore-installed six
```

Source: 1233 thumbs up on [this comment](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165#issuecomment-146666737)

Answer (score 3):

I did the following to solve the mentioned problem. I got the mentioned problem when I was trying to run the built exe, even I successfully built the exe using pyinstaller. I did this on Windows 10.

1. go to https://pypi.org/project/six/#files
2. download "six-1.14.0.tar.gz (33.9 kB)"
3. unzip it, copy and paste "six.py" into your source directory.
4. import "six" module into your source code (import six)
5. run source script.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, six was installed for python 2.7 and for 3.7 too, and both `pip install six` and `pip3 install six` reported it as already installed, while I still had apps (particularly, the apt program itself) complaining about missing six.

The solution was to install it for python3.6 specifically:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install six
```

Comment: You are a saviour! Was struggling with this problem for a while. Thank you so much for sharing your experience. Finally I also solved it because of you :)

Comment: Had this error everytime apt upgrade was run on Ubuntu 20.04. This worked but just substitute python3.6 with python3.8 in cmd.

Answer (score 2):

on Ubuntu Bionic (18.04), six is already install for python2 and python3 but I have the error launching Wammu.
@3ygun solution worked for me to solve

```
ImportError: No module named six
```

when launching Wammu

If it's occurred for python3 program, six come with

```
pip3 install six
```

and if you don't have pip3:

```
apt install python3-pip
```

with **sudo** under Ubuntu!

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver):

```
apt --reinstall install python3-debian
apt --reinstall install python3-six
```

If /usr/bin/chardet3 fails with error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'":

```
apt --reinstall install python3-pkg-resources
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue wasn't `six` but `rst2pdf` itself.  `head -1 $(which rst2pdf)` (3.8) didn't match `python3 --version` (3.9).  My solution:

```
pip3 install rst2pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

`six` is a Python module. The `python` command may refer to Python2.

It is possible that you are confusing Python2 and Python3, or that you confused the Python version number this module applies to. `six` for Python2 is distinct from `six` for Python3.

If installing `six` still does not work via pip, consider running Python3 instead.

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu and Debian**

Try to execute the following command-

```
 sudo apt install python-six
```

If it's not working perfectly then try to force it by using the following command-

```
/usr/local/bin/pip3 install six
```

I hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

With poetry you can add this package with `poetry add six`.

To more details, you can see the documentation [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add).

Answer (score 0):

For me this was some kind of issue with improper installation of required libraries. Had to run pip as a module by:

```bash
python -m pip install six
```

This is just fast fix, better check python env config. But it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This fix the issue of livecode for python in VS code Editor.

if pip says six is already installed.

you can try this
by changing the line no 3 of **init.py**_

`from six import StringIO` instead of `from six.moves import cStringIO`

and in the same file **change all cStringIO to StringIO**.
Then reopen the editor and try.

Answer (score 0):

in the _init_py file rename all the the cStringIO to StringIO and

from io import StringIO