# Can't open html5lib in Python

Tags: python, package, html5lib

I just installed html5lib for Python with Windows Command Prompt. The package was installed here:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\html5lib
```

However, if I try to import html5lib:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import html5lib
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\workspace\testhtml5\src\test.py", line 2, in <module>
import html5lib
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\html5lib\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 2, in <module>
from six import with_metaclass
ImportError: No module named six
```

Any idea on what might be causing the error? Thanks

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967428/importerror-no-module-named-six

Comment: It's not really a duplicate question - it's just a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `six` module. You can download it from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/), or better, use `pip install six` .