# Creating Graphs in Pythons using matplotlib: ERROR Module 6

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a graph on Python (version 3 and above) using matplotlib, however I keep getting the error saying

```
ImportError: No module named 'six'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have already tried downloading the module. And I still get this error.

Comment: See this question on how to install `six`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967428/importerror-no-module-named-six.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you've installed `six`?

If you have both python 2.x and 3.x installed, it may be that when running easy_install or pip, you're installing six for 2.x rather than 3.x. If you have pip, try running `pip3 install six` in a shell, or for easy_install, run `easy_install-3.4 six` (replace 3.4 with your 3.x python version).