# LLDB test failures while building Swift 5.0 toolchain

Tags: python, swift, lldb, swift5

LLDB test failures while building Swift 5.0 toolchain.

Sample test failure:

```
Testing: 0 .
FAIL: lldb-Suite :: benchmarks/disassembly/TestXcode41Vs42GDBDisassembly.py (116 of 1566)
******************** TEST 'lldb-Suite :: benchmarks/disassembly/TestXcode41Vs42GDBDisassembly.py' FAILED ********************
lldb version 7.0.0 (https://github.com/apple/swift-lldb.git revision 450ac50b3d6c87b246f22f6a883b15c02f372e0c)
Swift-5.0 (revision f6eeb3adca4f6ed7e66d4463883540c361e8f2cf)
clang revision ad7fb41b1dc11fb61584125212aec259ebc583db
llvm revision f63b283c7143aef31863d5915c28ee79ed390be3
LLDB library dir: /root/swift-source/build/buildbot_linux/lldb-linux-powerpc64le/bin
LLDB import library dir: /root/swift-source/build/buildbot_linux/lldb-linux-powerpc64le/bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/swift-source/lldb/test/dotest.py", line 7, in 
lldbsuite.test.run_suite()
File "/root/swift-source/lldb/packages/Python/lldbsuite/test/dotest.py", line 1258, in run_suite
import lldb
File "/root/swift-source/build/buildbot_linux/lldb-linux-powerpc64le/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lldb/init.py", line 53, in 
_lldb = swig_import_helper()
File "/root/swift-source/build/buildbot_linux/lldb-linux-powerpc64le/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lldb/init.py", line 49, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_lldb', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_lldb)


  Expected Passes    : 635
  Unsupported Tests  : 48
  Unexpected Failures: 883
```

Comment: I have installed all the development dependencies as mentioned in https://github.com/apple/swift:-

sudo apt-get install git cmake ninja-build clang python uuid-dev libicu-dev icu-devtools libbsd-dev libedit-dev libxml2-dev libsqlite3-dev swig libpython-dev libncurses5-dev pkg-config libblocksruntime-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev systemtap-sdt-dev tzdata rsync

I also tried setting the PYTHONPATH as mentioned in:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869945/how-to-import-lldb-in-a-python-script

The problem still persists and affects around 865 tests due to this reason.

Comment: Considering that not many people are trying to build Swift 5 from source, I'd say you have a better chance of getting an answer if you raise an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift).