# can't import google.oauth2.id_token

Tags: python, google-api, google-app-engine-python

So i am trying to authenticate user id token. but i get this weird error. it says no module named six.moves. some of you would say alright just do `pip install six` guess what ? when i try to install it pip says requirement already satisfied.
this is what i'm trying to achieve https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

here's where the error occurs `from google.oauth2 import id_token`

```
ERROR    2019-08-26 02:50:39,688 wsgi.py:269] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 311, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Users\Touseef\Desktop\Projects\base-project\base-project\Routes.py", line 3, in <module>
    from controllers import Home,social_sign_up
  File "C:\Users\Touseef\Desktop\Projects\base-project\base-project\controllers\social_sign_up.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.oauth2 import id_token
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\id_token.py", line 63, in <module>
    from six.moves import http_client
ImportError: No module named six.moves
INFO     2019-08-26 07:50:39,698 module.py:861] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

any idea how to resolve the error?

Comment: what operating system are you on? forgot to ask this earlier but i assume it's windows

Comment: your assumption is correct

Comment: answer posted below

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer:

[ImportError: No module named six](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967428/importerror-no-module-named-six)

If you can't access the link, it essentially says that you should uninstall six like so:

`pip uninstall six`

and then reinstall. Seems like you're using Python2.7, so

`pip install six`

works fine.